# Rx Reactive Streams Connectable Observables

Tags: java, scala, reactive-programming, subscription, observable

Reading through this document:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators

I have some questions governing the rules on which Connectable Observables work! This is what is explained in the Wiki:

```
The following example code shows two Subscribers subscribing to the same Observable. In the first case, they subscribe to an ordinary Observable; in the second case, they subscribe to a Connectable Observable that only connects after both Subscribers subscribe. Note the difference in the output: 

Example #1:

def firstMillion  = Observable.range( 1, 1000000 ).sample(7, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

firstMillion.subscribe(
   { println("Subscriber #1:" + it); },       // onNext
   { println("Error: " + it.getMessage()); }, // onError
   { println("Sequence #1 complete"); }       // onCompleted
);

firstMillion.subscribe(
    { println("Subscriber #2:" + it); },       // onNext
    { println("Error: " + it.getMessage()); }, // onError
    { println("Sequence #2 complete"); }       // onCompleted
);
Subscriber #1:211128
Subscriber #1:411633
Subscriber #1:629605
Subscriber #1:841903
Sequence #1 complete
Subscriber #2:244776
Subscriber #2:431416
Subscriber #2:621647
Subscriber #2:826996
Sequence #2 complete

Example #2:

def firstMillion  = Observable.range( 1, 1000000 ).sample(7, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish();

firstMillion.subscribe(
   { println("Subscriber #1:" + it); },       // onNext
   { println("Error: " + it.getMessage()); }, // onError
   { println("Sequence #1 complete"); }       // onCompleted
);

firstMillion.subscribe(
   { println("Subscriber #2:" + it); },       // onNext
   { println("Error: " + it.getMessage()); }, // onError
   { println("Sequence #2 complete"); }       // onCompleted
);

firstMillion.connect();
Subscriber #2:208683
Subscriber #1:208683
Subscriber #2:432509
Subscriber #1:432509
Subscriber #2:644270
Subscriber #1:644270
Subscriber #2:887885
Subscriber #1:887885
Sequence #2 complete
Sequence #1 complete
```

What I do not get is the following:

1. In the Example #2, how will the Observable know that there are two subscribers (in this case)
2. How to deal with scenarios where one of the subscriber is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question: Because two calls to `subscribe` are made.

To answer your second question: If this is a concern, you need to apply some backpressure algorithms to the observers which might be slow.

The RxJS repo has a [good introduction](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md) to some of the backpressure options available in RxJS.  I'm not sure how many of the mentioned operators exist in RxJava.  I know some of them do.